# linking a fortran code using netcdf3 to netcdf4

Tags: compilation, fortran, netcdf

some months ago, I posed a question about writing netcdf3 files with netcdf4 code. Now, I have another problem. I have an older fortran code, which runs in serial and is used to interpolate data from one mesh to another. The code is based on using netcdf3 files and I would like to recompile it with netcdf4. the code uses following netcdf functions:
nf_open, nf_put_vara_real etc. 
I'm far from being an expert, but as far as I've read, the code should still accept the netcdf4 files with these calls. However, when I try to compile it with netcdf4 I get lots of error messages. The code itself uses netcdf.inc which is in the same folder as the code, the compilation commands are as follows:

```
gfortran parameter.f90 netcdf_utils.f90 mean_streaks.f90 -L/opt/netcdf/netcdf3/lib/ -lnetcdf  -O2
```

I then tried just to change netcdf3 to 4 as I have netcdf3 and 4 folders under /opt/netcdf. However, I got for example the following error messages when compiling:

```
/tmp/ccgwLiTF.o: In function `__netcdf_utils_MOD_read3d':
netcdf_utils.f90:(.text+0x445): undefined reference to `nf_open_'
netcdf_utils.f90:(.text+0x4a0): undefined reference to `nf_get_vara_real_'
netcdf_utils.f90:(.text+0x4b4): undefined reference to `nf_close_'
```

Does anyone happen to know what I'm missing or how I should link the libraries to get the compilation done?

thanks for the answers in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add `-lnetcdff` to your compile command (yes, 2 f's).  In netcdf4 the Fortran symbols end up that library rather than libnetcdf.so.

```
gfortran parameter.f90 netcdf_utils.f90 mean_streaks.f90 -L/opt/netcdf/netcdf4/lib/ -lnetcdf -lnetcdff -O2
```

You can verify that the symbols are in that library with a command like

```
readelf -s libnetcdff.so | grep 'nf_*_'
```

The output of which, on my installation, includes all of the symbols listed in your error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The thing was that on the cluster I'm using, the netcdf4 was compiled with mpif90, not gfortran. So I changed the gfortran to mpif90 and used changed netcdf3 to netcdf4. I also added other links, for which I used the CMakeList for another code that uses netcdf4. The final working product is:

```
mpif90 parameter.f90 netcdf_utils.f90 mean_streaks.f90 -I/opt/netcdf/netcdf4/include -L/opt/netcdf/netcdf4/lib -lnetcdff -L/opt/pnetcdf/pnetcdf-1.2.0/lib -L/opt/netcdf/netcdf4/hdf5.1.8.8/lib -lnetcdf -lpnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lm -lz -lcurl -O2
```

thanks for the help, I now have another question which I'll be posting in a while:)